# Resize excel comments to fit text with specific width

Tags: vba, excel, comments

I'd like to have the comment box fit the comments just right (no extra space at the bottom).

I know there is the `.AutoSize` but I want the maximum width to be 300.

Here is the code I have,

```
For Each mycell In myRng.Cells
    If Not (mycell.Comment Is Nothing) Then
      With mycell.Comment.Shape
        .TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        If .width > 300 Then
          lArea = .width * .height
          .width = 300
          .height = (lArea / 300)
        End If
      End With
    End If
Next mycell
```

`mycell` and `myRng` are Range datatypes, `lArea` is Long.

Now, this works relatively well but leaves extra space at the bottom of a number of comments because the area the AutoSized text takes up is different from the area of the AutoSized comment box.

Is there a way to check for blank space inside a comment and then trim it? Or is what I have the best it is going to be?

Comment: Perhaps try `...Comment.Text = Trim(...Comment.Text)`?

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it by writing a word-wrap routine.  So the comment is auto-sized and no extra blank space at the bottom; and the width is limited.

Answer (score 4):

try this ... test comment has been placed in cell E4

discovered by putting `Range("e4").Comment.Shape.TextFrame` in the Watch window

```
Sub testComment()

    With Range("e4").Comment.Shape

        .TextFrame.AutoSize = True

        lArea = .Width * .Height

        .Width = 300
        .Height = (lArea / .Width)       ' used .width so that it is less work to change final width

        .TextFrame.AutoMargins = False
        .TextFrame.MarginBottom = 0      ' margins need to be tweaked
        .TextFrame.MarginTop = 0
        .TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0
        .TextFrame.MarginRight = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the code in the previous comment to only resize the box if width is above 300 because otherwise the final size of small boxes were messed up. Also changed to go through all comment box on activesheet

```
Sub reset_box_size()
Dim pComment As Comment
For Each pComment In Application.ActiveSheet.Comments
    With pComment.Shape

        .TextFrame.AutoSize = True

        lArea = .Width * .Height
        
        'only resize the autosize if width is above 300
        If .Width > 300 Then .Height = (lArea / .Width)       ' used .width so that it is less work to change final width

        
        .TextFrame.AutoMargins = False
        .TextFrame.MarginBottom = 0      ' margins need to be tweaked
        .TextFrame.MarginTop = 0
        .TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0
        .TextFrame.MarginRight = 0
        End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like your method will never adjust the width after the AutoSize call. So e.g. if AutoSize ended up at 450, your method will make the box taller but won't pull it in to 300. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

there is an `autosize`function.

here is a small code to show how to use:

```
Dim Rg_Com as Range , Rg_Value as Range
Set Rg_Com = Cells(1,1)
Set Rg_Value = Cells(1,2)

'Comment in A1 will be same as Text in B1:
With Rg_Com
    .ClearComments
    .AddComment
    With .Comment
        .Text Text:=Rg_Value.Value2
        .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True  '<<< just to make all text visible in one comment, all chars having the basic size
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below works well for me.
Using the idea of anonymous (lArea) a comment will be created with the content of the cell and deleted after afterwards. The runs also if the cell "C" is a merged area. I use it in large tables with small font size to make it easier to read. Just click at the cell you want to read and click enter to finish.

```
Function showComment(C As Range)

'variables
Dim cmnt          As Comment
Dim rg            As Range
Dim iArea         As Long

'settings
Set rg = C
Set C = C.Cells(1, 1)

'pre
With C
  If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then .Comment.Delete
  Set cmnt = .AddComment
End With

'main
With cmnt
  .Text Replace(C, vbLf, " ")                                 'otherwhile the comment area is to long
  With .Shape
    With .TextFrame
      .Characters.Font.Name = "Calibri"
      .Characters.Font.Size = 16
      .AutoMargins = False
      .MarginLeft = 10
      .MarginTop = 10
      .MarginRight = 10
      .MarginBottom = 10
    End With
    .TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    iArea = .Width * .Height
    .Top = C.Top - 89                                         'change .left according to your needs
    .Left = C.Left                                            'change .left according to your needs
    .Width = rg.Width * 3                                     'change .width according to your needs
    .Height = IIf(iArea / .Width <= 263, 263, iArea / .Width) 'change 263 according to your needs
    .Visible = msoCTrue
  End With
  .Text IIf(C.Value = "", " ", C.Value)                       'otherwhile it struggle if C is empty
End With

'CleanUp
Set rg = Nothing
Set cmnt = Nothing

End Function
```

The function will be started in "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)" with following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'variables
Dim rgComment             as Range
Dim rgOld                 As Range
Dim blnScreenUpdating     As Boolean
Dim blnEnableEvents       As Boolean

'settings
Set rgComment = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet1.name).Range("D15:AG15") 'set rgComment according to your needs
Set rgOld = ActiveCell

'assignments
blnScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
blnEnableEvents = Application.EnableEvents

'pre
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = False

'interception
If Target.Count > 1 Then
  If Not Target.MergeCells Then 'used for my code, change it according to your needs
    GoTo releaseSub
  End If
End If

'------------------------------------------------------------
'main
'------------------------------------------------------------

'comment
If Not Intersect(Target, rgComment) Is Nothing Then
  With Target
    showComment C:=Target
    Do
      DoEvents
    Loop Until Intersect(ActiveCell, Target) Is Nothing
  End With
  Target.Comment.Delete
End If

'Post
releaseSub:
Target.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = blnScreenUpdating
Application.EnableEvents = blnEnableEvents

'CleanUp
Set rgComment = nothing
Set rgOld = Nothing

End Sub
```